Upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8, errored out with "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=8.0.0.0"
I am working on upgrading the Azure function application version from .net6 to .net8 but what so ever I try I end up with the below error
Found C:\XXXXXXXX\Project.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
Error configuring services in an external startup class.
Error configuring services in an external startup class. Project: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation 'f5a77300-36f2-4210-803e-0ef503e6f29d'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. Project: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
What I have tried:

Installed the latest/lower version of 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options'
Updated all the packages through Nuget Manager
Updated all the projects in the solution with Visual Studio ->
Upgrade Assitant tool
In a different approach even tried upgrading the project manually to
.NET 8
Updated the local.settings file with
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

project csproj
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.13.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Formats.Asn1" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Contract\Project.Contract.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Data\Project.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Data\RecourceType.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


can you share your function code

please add the csproj as well. Sounds like you are doing isolated function?
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.* are normally in-process functions. Can you verify you are not using any WebJob packages?

Maybe this question could be related

@JulianHüppauff, the function application is In-Process model, I tried updating it to Isolated Function just to see if the error is resolved

@JulianHüppauff I am using 3 Webjob packages, can you help me to point out what is wrong with using them, kindly have a look at the csproj file above

please share function code as well

Please upgrade according to this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-isolated-overview You need the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask for durable

Regarding Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" I am not sure if you need that. What happens if you try to remove it? I am not sure which package replaces that

Can you also share your program.cs class. I am interessted how you configured the startup

When you see assembly version mismatch exceptions like this, it is likely because another older version was already loaded. Check that your runtime is configured correctly and that you have removed all obsolete/deprecated Nuget packages.

I'd consider creating a completely fresh Azure Functions project using the latest .NET  templates and then just copy your source code across. This will mean you get all the latest dependencies and remove all that trouble of working out what to upgrade. The biggest changes will be updating your Function definitions to be Isolated, but you'd have to do that even if you stick with the current .csproj anyway.

I can see you still have In-process related packages in .csproj.
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.13.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core" Version="1.5.1" />

If you are migrating the functions from In-process to isolated model, you have to install the packages accordingly.
Uninstall or remove the above-mentioned packages and install the below worker packages, refer MSDOC.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi

I have created a simple .NET 8.0 isolated Azure Durable function.
.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.18.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}

Response:

